# C++ card validation issue

Tags: c++, luhn

I'm a bit of a coding noob and I'm trying to get a simple Luhn algorithm to do a credit card validation check. I've got this far and I can't quite see what's wrong with the way I've done it, but the answer is always true.

If anyone can help, I'd be really grateful.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;

bool validate(char card_number[]);

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   cout << validate(argv[1]) << endl;
   return 0;
}

bool validate(char card_number[])
{
   bool valid = false;
   int length = 0;
   int step_1 = 0;
   int step_2 = 0;
   int result = 0;

   while (card_number[length] != '\0') {
       length++;
   }


   for (int i = card_number[0]; i < card_number[length]; i++) {

       if (( i % 2 != 0 && i != 0)) {

           int temp = card_number[i] - '0';

           if((temp / 10) >= 1) {
               step_1 = step_1 + (temp / 10) + (temp % 10);
           } else {

               step_1 = step_1 + temp;             
           }
       } else {

           step_2 = step_2 + card_number[i] - '0';         
       }
   }
   result = step_1 + step_2;

   if (result % 10 == 0) {
       valid = true;
   }

   return valid;
}
```

Comment: `for (int i = card_number[0]; i < card_number[length]; i++) {` What are you trying to achieve here? Remember that `card_number` is a null-terminated (hopefully) array.

Comment: @Bob__  for (int i = card_number[0]; i < card_number[length]; i++) I was hoping this would put the integer value of the array location into i, so it can be determined as odd or even.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To implement the Luhn algorithm (at least the one described in [this Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luhn_algorithm)) you should iterate through each digit of the card number and apply some transformations.

After calculating the length of the number, the loop in the posted code looks like this

```
for (int i = card_number[0]; i < card_number[length]; i++) { // ...
//           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Where `card_number` is a null-terminated `char` array inputted by the command line, so that the former is equivalent to something like

```
for (int i = '7'; i < 0; i++) { // ...
//           ^^^      ^  Note that any "digit" would have a value greater than 0
```

This loop would be just skipped and `result` would always remain equal to 0.

The rest of the code seems partial or not conforming to algorithm (if the one I linked is the actual one needed by the OP). Here is a possible implementation.

```
if (length == 0)
    return false;

int sum = 0;
// Loop over the array from the beginning (the "left" side of the number)
for (int i = 0; i < length - 1; ++i)
{
    int digit = card_number[i] - '0';

    // Now determine if this is an odd or even position, but from the
    // "right" side of the number
    if ( (length - 1 - i) % 2 )
    {
        // You missed this part, according to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luhn_algorithm
        digit *= 2;

        // If it's not a single digit anymore...
        if ( digit > 9 )
        {
            // Reduce to one digit again
            digit -= 9;               
        }
    }

    sum += digit;
}

// You missed this part too, always according to Wikipedia
if ( (sum * 9) % 10  !=  card_number[length - 1] - '0') {
    return false;
}

return true;
```

Answer (score 0):

As someone else said in the comments, you have to loop through array indexes, not array elements.

Also, according to Luhn's algorithm, your condition **if((temp / 10) >= 1)** is wrong (will never be met) since **temp** is a digit and it can never be higher than 9. What you have to do instead is validate that the double of the digit (**temp**) is higher or equal to 10.